# Pass column name to function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a function in which i want to pass pandas dataframe's column name.

Basically i am using plotly.express and that is what i am embedding into a function.

But when i am doing so, it is saying that plotly requires column name but no colomn name found.

````
def bar(df,**kwargs):
    val=", ".join(f"{key}={value}"  for key, value in kwargs.items())
    px.bar(df,val).show()
    
    
bar(sales,x='Category',y='Quantity')```
````

How can i solve this.
So that whenever user passes an argument it consider it as a field not just a string.

Any leads will be helpful.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a **plotly** question,  but **python**.  Fundamentals of how argument passing works.

Simply you just need to pass the **kwargs** pass to your function to `px.bar()`

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def bar(df,**kwargs):
    px.bar(df,**kwargs).show()
    

sales = pd.DataFrame({"Category":np.random.choice(list("ABCD"), 20), "Quantity":np.random.randint(1,10,20)})
bar(sales,x='Category',y='Quantity')
```